# Send formatted char array to ostream without extra memory copying

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, iomanip

I need to send a char array to ostream. Say I have the following print function:

Version 1:

```
void print(ostream &out, const char *str, unsigned len)
{
    out << string(str,len);
}
```

Version 2:

```
void print(ostream &out, const char *str, unsigned len)
{
    out.write(str,len);
}
```

Both versions above work to a certain extent.
Version 1 looks less efficient because it will create an extra string object (causing memory allocation and data copying).

However Version 2 eliminates formatting possibilities. In the following example Version 1 works great (meaning that io manipulator successfully sets width to 10 and applies it to the next output field) :

```
out << setw(10);
print(out,s,slen);
```

Is there a way to keep functionality as in V1, but without paying extra for allocation/memcopy?

Comment: Both version are wrong (not taking a ostream&)

Comment: And as usual:  Be not(!) concerned about optimizations unless you have a performance problem or a flawed algorithm.

Comment: I fixed typo in my example. Thanks for pointing out. Yes it should be ostream&.

Comment: Does your string contain NUL bytes or isn't guaranteed to be NUL-terminated?  If the answer to both questions is “no”, simply use `os << str`.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to be null-terminated.

Comment: First, if the cost of `std::string(str,len)` is significant in any way then I would question whether it is a good idea to print that string at all, except possibly if this is only going to a data file. Second, I would be wary of _other_ inefficiencies that might crop up in any alternative technique.

Comment: @DieterLücking ostreams are slow enough as it is, it seems reasonable to ask how to avoid an extra heap allocation and free which would be associated with a std::string (if the data is too big for SSO)

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy or reasonable way to do this.

The underlying issue is that `operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, ...>&, basic_string<charT, ...>)` is defined as behaving equivalent to `operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, ...>&, const charT*)`, which calculates the number of characters to write via `basic_ostream<charT, ...>::traits_type::length(str)`. There's no possibility of passing in a length with this interface.

If you can re-write it to take `char*` instead of `const char*`, you can temporarily set one of the characters to `NULL` before invoking the formatted output operator, and then reset it to it's original value after.

There was a proposal to add `basic_string_view`, which would do what you're looking for, but it wasn't included in C++14.

Comment: For the sake of completion, you can write a massive hack that invokes a plethora of undefined behavior to get what you're looking for, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: I guess in my case I will need to make these char arrays null-terminanted. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [boost::iterator_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html) to stop the copying, as in:

```
out << boost::iterator_range<const char*>(str, str + len);
```

I don't think you can affect the formatting, as that is based in the type being inserted into the stream.

Comment: is that the same as `out.write(str,len);` ?